# Updating a single value in a sorted data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I need a data structure that is able to:

1. Add one value
2. Get the lowest value
3. Update one value

I can achieve this using `std::multiset`, where the operations are imlemented as:

1. `multiset::insert()`
2. `multiset::begin()`
3. first remove the item using `multiset::erase()` then add updated item using `multiset::insert()`

One thing I don't like with `multiset` is that an iterator is required to update an item. It would be nice if a pointer was enough.

I wonder if it would be better to use `std::priority_queue`, std heap algorithms or anything else for the operations required and how to do it. The first two operations are straightforward for the `std::priority_queue` or the heap algorithms, but the third operation (updating) is a problem. Are there any other structures that can be used? What are their performance benefits over `multiset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` will give you efficient insertions and lowest value queries, but updates will be slow. You can make updates efficient by storing pointers in both a PQ and a `std::vector` and using the vector to perform updates. To perform an update, mark the entry as stale and insert a new updated copy. Then when querying the lowest value, ignore stale entries.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to have a few disadvantages over multiset. It is much harder to use as two containers have to be synchronized, so a wrapper would be needed. Theoretical complexity for getting the lowest element is O(N). Memory overhead for slate entries. What are the advantages?

Comment: @Juraj Lowest element is O(1), popping it O(logN). Updates will be O(1) whereas `std::multiset` will take O(logN). But then many updates will slow down lowest queries. You'll have to compare them based on your usage characteristics. Both are good solutions, I was just giving an alternative.

Comment: @marcog: have you thrown your hat into the  moderator election pool?  I think you'd be good at it.

Comment: @David Thanks, I appreciate the nudge. I won't have the time throughout 2011 to dedicate towards it though.

Comment: @marcog: How is the update possible in O(1)? Inserting an element into priority_queue takes O(log(N)) time.

Comment: @Juraj Erm, you're right. Go with the multiset then. Although you'll probably find pq has a lower constant factor in its operations. I'd test both if performance is crucial.

Comment: Thanks anyway, the principle of invalidating items is worth to remember.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `multiset` should have good characteristics for what you need.

You'll need to consider which operations need to be fastest. If update is relatively rare a `priority_queue` may be better. If you use the `priority_queue` one option to make the `update` faster is to simply mark the old item invalid (assuming you have a reference/pointer to it) and add the new item+reheapify. Then when you pull off the lowest item first make sure it hasn't been marked invalid before using it (else get the next lowest item). This technique is useful any time it's somewhat expensive to remove an item from a container.